# Rational roots of x^5 + a x + b

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I'm validating a formula from these article:

- https://www.annals-csis.org/Volume_20/drp/pdf/164.pdf
- [https://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/185.pdf](https://people.math.carleton.ca/%7Ewilliams/papers/pdf/185.pdf)

If irreducible rational equation $x^5 + a x + b$ has solutions, then it can be written as:

\begin{aligned}
v_ 1=+\sqrt{d}+\sqrt{d-e\sqrt{d}}\\
v_ 2=-\sqrt{d}-\sqrt{d+e\sqrt{d}}\\
v_ 3=-\sqrt{d}+\sqrt{d+e\sqrt{d}}\\
v_ 4=+\sqrt{d}-\sqrt{d-e\sqrt{d}}\\
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
u_ 1=\sqrt[5]{\frac{p^5 v_ 1^2 v_ 3}{d^2}}\\
u_ 2=\sqrt[5]{\frac{p^5 v_ 3^2 v_ 4}{d^2}}\\
u_ 3=\sqrt[5]{\frac{p^5 v_ 2^2 v_ 1}{d^2}}\\
u_ 4=\sqrt[5]{\frac{p^5 v_ 4^2 v_ 2}{d^2}}\\
\end{aligned}

$$x_i = w^i u_1 + w^{2i} u_2+ w^{3i} u_3+ w^{4i} u_4, i=\{0,1,2,3,4\},$$

where $w=e^{2\pi i / 5}$.

I translated it into the following codes:

```
getPseudoRoot[a_, b_, paras_] := Module[
    {u, v},
    Subscript[v, 1] = + Sqrt[d] + Sqrt[d - e Sqrt[d]];
    Subscript[v, 2] = - Sqrt[d] - Sqrt[d + e Sqrt[d]];
    Subscript[v, 3] = - Sqrt[d] + Sqrt[d + e Sqrt[d]];
    Subscript[v, 4] = + Sqrt[d] - Sqrt[d - e Sqrt[d]];
    Subscript[u, 1] = p^5 Subscript[v, 1]^2 * Subscript[v, 3] / d^2;
    Subscript[u, 2] = p^5 Subscript[v, 3]^2 * Subscript[v, 4] / d^2;
    Subscript[u, 3] = p^5 Subscript[v, 2]^2 * Subscript[v, 1] / d^2;
    Subscript[u, 4] = p^5 Subscript[v, 4]^2 * Subscript[v, 2] / d^2;
    Table[Subscript[u, i], {i, 1, 4}] /. paras
];
getRational[a_, b_] := Solve[
    {
        a == 5p^4(3 - 4 e q) / (q^2 + 1),
        b == -4p^5(11e + 2  q) / (q^2 + 1),
        e^2 == 1,
        d == q^2 + 1,
        q >= 0,
        p != 0
    },
    {p, e, q, d}, Rationals
];
getRoot[a_, b_] := Module[
    {paras, pseudo, z},
    paras = getRational[a, b];
    If[Length@paras == 0, Return[Failure["NoSolution", <||>]]];
    pseudo = getPseudoRoot[a, b, First@paras];
    Table[Sum[pseudo[[i]]^(1 / 5)Exp[2Pi I / 5]^(i j), {i, 1, 4}], {j, 0, 4}]
];
```

However, the solution calculated by this formula is completely different from the numerical solution.

```
SortBy[getRoot[11, 44] // N, Im]
SortBy[x /. NSolve[x^5 + 11 x + 44 == 0, x], Im]
```

What's wrong with my code that I can't reproduce the formula?

---

#### Update 20220517

On further research, I found a new case where \zeta can be an imaginary number:

```
eq = x^5 + x^4 - 4 x^3 - 3 x^2 + 3 x + 1;
{a, b} = {
    -(1 / 5),
    {
        Root[25937424601 + 492715403125 # + 4562314453125 #^2 + 29876708984375 #^3 + 95367431640625 #^4& , 1, 0],
        Root[25937424601 + 492715403125 # + 4562314453125 #^2 + 29876708984375 #^3 + 95367431640625 #^4& , 2, 0],
        Root[25937424601 + 492715403125 # + 4562314453125 #^2 + 29876708984375 #^3 + 95367431640625 #^4& , 3, 0],
        Root[25937424601 + 492715403125 # + 4562314453125 #^2 + 29876708984375 #^3 + 95367431640625 #^4& , 4, 0]
    }
};
Solve[Factor[eq, Extension -> ToRadicals@First[b]^(1/5)] == 0]
```

Which case none of the following methods give the correct root

```
x /. NSolve[eq == 0, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
N[Tr@Surd[b, 5] + a, 50]
N[Tr[b^(1 / 5)] + a, 50]
N[Tr[Sign[b] * Abs[b]^(1 / 5)] + a, 50]
```

How should I get the correct root in this case?

Comment: Aren't you missing the square roots, e.g. `Subscript[u, 1] = Sqrt[p^5 + ...`?

Comment: @ChrisDegnen, it was in `pseudo[[i]]^(1 / 5)`, I put it outside because it affects `FullSimplify`

Comment: Programming note: The localization of `u` and `v` is subverted by the use of `Subscript`. Best not to use `Subscript` as a variable to store values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the array `pseudo`

```
(* {-0.510481,-0.143328,-6.43215,1.80596} *)
```

These are real numbers, but if any of these numbers is negative, you get a complex value, when exponentiated to one-fifth.

Change last line

```
Table[Sum[Sign[pseudo[[i]]]*Abs[pseudo[[i]]]^(1/5) * Exp[2Pi I / 5]^(i j), {i, 1, 4}], {j, 0, 4}]
```

Now I get the same numerical result as when using NSolve

```
(* {-0.861241 - 1.9105 I, 1.80012 - 1.44746 I, -1.87775, 1.80012 + 1.44746 I, -0.861241 + 1.9105 I} *)
```

Comment: Seems `Surd[x, 5]` also works, I'm looking for more examples to verify.

Comment: Yes, also possible.

Comment: It's interesting that `Solve[x^5 + 11 x + 44 == 0, x] // ToRadicals` is unable to express roots in radicals.

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec `Solve[Factor[x^5 + 11 x + 44, Extension -> First@ getPseudoRoot[11, 44, {p -> -1, e -> 1, q -> 2/11, d -> 125/121}]^(1/5)] == 0]` gives the roots in terms of radicals.